# Python script - connect to SSH and run command

Tags: ssh, python, telnet

What I want to have is an python script to do the following:

1. connect to an [ input by user ] SSH host
2. connect using the credentials [ provided by the user ]
3. run command on the SSH host [ telnet to [host - input by user ]
4. Select menu item in the telnet session

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @Alex Holst, I want a python script that do the following steps, i described above.

Comment: I can't think of anything that meets those requirements. If you instead tell us what you're trying to achieve, we might be able to help. For instance, is there any particular reason the user can't just type ssh user@hostname 'menu-item-6'?

Answer (score 5):

I use [fabric](http://docs.fabfile.org/0.9.3/). Fabric is a Python library and command-line tool for streamlining the use of SSH for application deployment or systems administration tasks.

Comment: Ok,thank for your answer. But I'm looking for a start script.

Comment: you were given a python library that can do what you need. Are you expecting people to write your scripts for you, for free?

Comment: @dyasny: at least a nice website. Someone found this: http://jessenoller.com/2009/02/05/ssh-programming-with-paramiko-completely-different/